# Use trigger with code operating on two databases

Tags: mysql, triggers

How can I use a trigger that accesses two databases?

This is what I tried:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `db1`.`library_AFTER_UPDATE`

AFTER UPDATE ON `library` FOR EACH ROW
begin
insert into `db2`.email(account_code,account_name,admin_first_name,admin_email,last_updated_date,updated_by) values('146','Abcds','SSSSSSSS','jnkjk@gmli',now(),'anupam');
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jan but you know the answer.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example on after Update trigger. I am using 2 databases test and test2. This example can help you-

```
use test
create table test.foo (a INT, b INT, ts TIMESTAMP);
create table test2.bar (a INT, b INT);

INSERT INTO test.foo (a,b) VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO test.foo (a,b) VALUES(2,2);
INSERT INTO test.foo (a,b) VALUES(3,3);

DELIMITER ///

CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO test2.bar (a, b) VALUES(NEW.a, NEW.b);
    END;
///

DELIMITER ;

select * from test.foo;
+------+------+---------------------+
| a    | b    | ts                  |
+------+------+---------------------+
|    1 |    1 | 2011-06-14 09:29:46 |
|    2 |    2 | 2011-06-14 09:29:46 |
|    3 |    3 | 2011-06-14 09:29:46 |
+------+------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

-- UPDATE without change
UPDATE test.foo SET b = 3 WHERE a = 3;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

select * from test2.bar;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    3 |    3 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```